# Generate Pattern from Regex String in Flutter

Tags: regex, flutter, dart, pattern-matching

I want to generate a Pattern from a String regex. I have Java code which needs to be converted into dart.

Java Code:

```
String pattern = "(XY.+)(?=52)";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = pat.matcher(qrString);
String tmpId = null;

if (m.find()) {
  tmpId = m.group(0);
}
```

Comment: Is your code broken? What is the issue?

Comment: This is in Java and I want to implement it into my Flutter app.